# Android calculator error message when dividing by 0

Tags: android, error-handling, exception

I'm new to Android Studio and have a calculator app that i'm working on. Right now when i divide by zero, naturally i get the error message "Infinity", but what if i wanted to change it to say, "Could not divide by zero", how would i go about it?

[image]

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Divisionpage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Button btnDiv;
        private TextView AnswDiv;
        private EditText Divt1, Divt2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_divisionssida);
            init();
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }

        private void init() {
            btnDiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
            AnswDiv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AnswDiv);
            Divt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Divtal1);
            Divt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Divtal2);
            btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String num7 = Divt1.getText().toString();
            String num8 = Divt2.getText().toString();
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnDiv:
                    try {
                        float division = Float.parseFloat(num7) / Float.parseFloat(num8);
                        AnswDiv.setText(String.valueOf(division));
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        AnswDiv.setText("Could not divide!");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried catching the exception to display an error message as you can see but it failed. What do you propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could actually check num8 value and if its 0 set the correct message.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String num7 = Divt1.getText().toString();
        String num8 = Divt2.getText().toString();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnDiv:
                try {
                    final float denominator = Float.parseFloat(num8);
                    if(denominator == 0){
                        AnswDiv.setText("Can't divide by zero");
                        return;
                    }
                    float division = Float.parseFloat(num7) / Float.parseFloat(num8);
                    AnswDiv.setText(String.valueOf(division));
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    AnswDiv.setText("Could not divide!");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

You could further improve the user experience improving exception handling, for example:
Unless restricted in the edittext MIME users could be introducing non numeric characters. Trying to parse said character will throw NumberFormatException which will be caught in you exception clause and set you message. This while not wrong can be improved informing the user that only numeric character are valid.

```
catch (NumberFormatException ex){
     AnswDiv.setText("Only numbers allowed!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I just want to ask, what's the point of the catch exception in your code if that specific error message doesn't get displayed("Could not divide!") ? Sorry if it's a stupid question but i'm learning.

Comment: catch (NumberFormatException ex){
     AnswDiv.setText("Only numbers allowed!");
}  is in case users input letter in your text box. The Exception clause is useless (unless ofcourse AnswDiv is null)

Comment: Also if the answer solved the issue would you mind accepting it? :)

Comment: I was thinking of the catch exception on your first code: }catch (Exception e) {
                    AnswDiv.setText("Could not divide!");
                }

Comment: Oh that was on you original post, my bad for not exlcuding it. That is not working because diving float by zero does not raise any exception, hence the catch block is never executed and you don't see "Could not divide". Was I clear?

Comment: Yes, i understand it better now. Thanks for the help but you might edit your post to exclude it :)